# Change filter options highlight color HTML

Tags: html, css, dom, bootstrap-4

I have a html page showing list of books. The books can be filtered on various metrics like genre etc.
Now When I select the genre filter and hover over the options to select, they are highlighted by blue color as shown below.

[image]

I want to change this color to match with my site theme.
How can I change this color if possible?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use [select2](https://select2.org/) or [chosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) library. These libraries allow you to style the way you want.